# My Scroll function is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, scroll, safari

I'm aware that Sarari does not support smooth scrolling with JS. However, I'm okay with just the default behavior of auto. However my app doesn't seem to be doing that in Safari. It works in Chrome. Just fine. I've tried other scrollIntoView default JS function with the same arguments but nothing is happing.

I have this function

```
export const scrollIntoView = (node) => {
  if (!node) return;
  const element = ReactDom.findDOMNode(node);
  try {
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "auto",
      block: "start",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    element.scrollIntoView(false);
  }
};
```

I'm then using my function like this. I pass it in an onClick.

```
const myDom = document.querySelector("#root');

scrollIntoView(myDom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately scrollIntoView is buggy on Safari.
You can use a polyfill and will work
https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamless-scroll-polyfill

Comment: This isn't accurate – `scrollIntoView` is absolutely supported in Safari, it simply does not support the `smooth` behavior option in 15.4. https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollintoview

Comment: Even without smooth behaviour, scrollIntoView is way too buggy, unless I miss something.

Comment: That can be true that it has issues in various cases, but I am saying you shouldn't claim it is not supported when it is on the support table. "Not supported" for a web API typically means you can't use it at all, attempting to do so may generate a thrown error, or something like that.

Comment: Edit my comment. Sorry for that:)